# How i can access to children pages widgets of a page on Apostrophe CMS

Tags: node.js, nunjucks, apostrophe-cms

I have the following code on one of my project page:

```
{% if data.page %}
    <ul>
    {%for child in data.page._children %}
    <li><a href="{{ child._url}}"></a>{{child.title}}
    <p>{{ apos.area(child, 'excerpt', 
            { widgets: 
                { 'apostrophe-rich-text': 
                    {
                    toolbar: [ 
                       'Styles', 
                       'Bold', 
                       'Italic', 
                       'Link',
                       'Unlink'] 
                    }
                }
            })
        }}
    </p>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Where 'excerpt' is a area on all children pages of the current page, but when the page is displayed I only see a empty box:
[empty box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkOtb.png)

I see on the docs something similiar [how to: children and joins](https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/howtos/children-and-joins.html), but I´m not sure where to put the example code for this to work(maybe the docs are not enough clear).

Please can give me some advice, thank you.

Comment: You're not getting any errors either on the server or in the browser console? I used your exact code above and things worked as expected. You're sure you are logged in?

Comment: yeah, I´m logged in but I no see any widgets buttons... maybe the issue is caused by my  installation of apostrophe. Anyway I implemented a solution based on apostrophe-blog module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[There is now an official HOWTO answering this question on the Apostrophe documentation site.](https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/howtos/thumbnails-and-areas-of-child-pages.html) Briefly, the answer is that you must configure `apostrophe-pages` to load more than just basic information about related pages. There is a performance tradeoff, of course, but you can limit this by instructing Apostrophe to load images only for the singleton or area name that you are using for this purpose.